# is not null or not equal clause in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

does cassandra java datastax driver has a support for not equal operations or at least filtering nulls?
Something like

```
query = QueryBuilder.select().from(table).where(field.ne(null))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try:

```
select * from mytable where column_which_might_contain_null >= '';
```

if your `column_which_might_contain_null` is a `text` column.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a problem of the driver. Cassandra doesn't support the "is not null" operator nor the "is not equal" operator. Have a look at [supported operators](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause). So there's no way to filter nulls either.

By the way, if you have these needs, I think you probably have a problem in your model.